# How can I join two associations into one query not using merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.

In this app I got Project objects that has_many Events and Meetings.
Event and Meeting each has_many CalendarItems.

I want to get all CalendarItems for a Project as an ActiveRecord relation. I am able to do it now by merging two queries but then I get an Array but I need to do some additional filtering and pagination so I need a real ActiveRecord relation.

**Project**

```
has_many :events
has_many :meetings
has_many :event_calendar_items, through: :events, source: "calendar_item"
has_many :meeting_calendar_items, through: :meetings, source: "calendar_item"
```

**Meeting**

```
has_many :calendar_items
```

**Event**

```
has_many :calendar_items
```

**CalendarItem**

```
belongs_to :calendar
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :meeting
```

**When I do this it works but produces an Array:**

```
event_calendar_items + meeting_calendar_items
```

**This results in a ActiveRecord relation with Projects:**

```
Project.joins(:event_calendar_items, :meeting_calendar_items)
```

**I tried this in the Project model and it works but it feels hacky(?)**

```
def calendar_items
  event_ids = self.event_calendar_items.pluck(:id)
  meeting_ids = self.meeting_calendar_items.pluck(:id)
  CalendarItem.where(id: event_ids + meeting_ids)
end
```

How can I make a real ActiveRecord relation that I can use for more filtering? Some sort of joins?

Comment: Is there a model for CalendarItem? What are the relationships there?

Comment: Updated the question with the CalendarItem relationships. Thanks!

Comment: What about `CalendarItem.joins(:event, :meeting).where(events: { project_id: id })`? If you have an instantiated project object. Both `events` and/or `meetings` should work interchangeably because they both have a column `project_id` and are related to the project model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an SQL SELECT this would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM calendar_items
  JOIN events WHERE events.id = calendar_items.event_id
  JOIN meetings WHERE meetings.id = calendar_items.meeting_id
WHERE
  events.project_id = ? OR meetings.project_id = ?
```

so I think you could do it like so:

```
def calendar_items
  items = CalendarItem.joins(:event, :meeting)
  items.where('events.project_id = ?', self.id).or(items.where('meetings.project_id = ?', self.id))
end
```

I haven't tested this so not sure but looks OK.